# Square button(x^2) exception handling error in Calculator android app development

Tags: java, android, onclick, calculator

I am currently trying to develop a Calculator android app in android studio using Java. The app works fine until I click the button for Square operation i.e. `x^2` button in the app when there is no input taken or when I click the Square operation button after any operator. For e.g. When I enter the input `1+` and then when I try to enter `x^2`, it automatically exit from the app. I tried multiple Try catch block in order to stop the app from abruptly existing but it didn't work
Below I have the code for onClick method of Square button

```java
bsquare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (tvMain.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter a valid number..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        double d = Double.parseDouble(tvMain.getText().toString());
                        double square = d * d;
                        tvMain.setText(String.valueOf(square));
                        tvsec.setText(d + "²");
                    }
                }
            });
```

I tried exception handling for stoping the app from abruplty existing but that didn't work

Comment: You should edit your question and paste the exception message and stack trace from the logcat into your question. Only then can we see why your app is crashing.

Comment: Your code is most likely failing on `Double.parseDouble` if the string is not a valid double (like "1+"). If you "tried exception handling" - show what you tried and describe what happened with actual information, not just "it didn't work". Show the Logcat with the full error message.

Comment: Please share also error message

Answer (score 0):

> *"... The app works fine until I click the button for Square operation i.e. `x^2` button in the app when there is no input taken or when I click the Square operation button after any operator. ..."*

Additionally check if *tvMain.getText().toString()* can be parsed without throwing a *[NumberFormatException](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html)*.
And, I suggest using *[String#isBlank](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#isBlank())* over *[isEmpty](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty())*.

In this example I am using a *boolean* to contain the input validity.
Only setting it to *true* once it has parsed successfully.

```java
bsquare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String string = tvMain.getText().toString();
        boolean valid = false;
        double d = 0;
        if (string != null && !string.isBlank()) {
            try {
                d = Double.parseDouble(string);
                valid = true;
            } catch (NumberFormatException exception) { }
        }
        if (!valid)
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter a valid number..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else {
            double square = d * d;
            tvMain.setText(String.valueOf(square));
            tvsec.setText(d + "²");
        }
    }
});
```

The *Java* documentation for *Double#valueOf* has some helpful information on this type of input situation.

*[Double#valueOf (Java SE 20 & JDK 20)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf(java.lang.String))*,

> *... To avoid calling this method on an invalid string and having a NumberFormatException be thrown, the regular expression below can be used to screen the input string:*
>
> ```java
> final String Digits     = "(\\p{Digit}+)";
> final String HexDigits  = "(\\p{XDigit}+)";
> // an exponent is 'e' or 'E' followed by an optionally
> // signed decimal integer.
> final String Exp        = "[eE][+-]?"+Digits;
> final String fpRegex    =
>     ("[\\x00-\\x20]*"+  // Optional leading "whitespace"
>      "[+-]?(" + // Optional sign character
>      "NaN|" +           // "NaN" string
>      "Infinity|" +      // "Infinity" string
>
>      // A decimal floating-point string representing a finite positive
>      // number without a leading sign has at most five basic pieces:
>      // Digits . Digits ExponentPart FloatTypeSuffix
>      //
>      // Since this method allows integer-only strings as input
>      // in addition to strings of floating-point literals, the
>      // two sub-patterns below are simplifications of the grammar
>      // productions from section 3.10.2 of
>      // The Java Language Specification.
>
>      // Digits ._opt Digits_opt ExponentPart_opt FloatTypeSuffix_opt
>      "((("+Digits+"(\\.)?("+Digits+"?)("+Exp+")?)|"+
>
>      // . Digits ExponentPart_opt FloatTypeSuffix_opt
>      "(\\.("+Digits+")("+Exp+")?)|"+
>
>      // Hexadecimal strings
>      "((" +
>       // 0[xX] HexDigits ._opt BinaryExponent FloatTypeSuffix_opt
>       "(0[xX]" + HexDigits + "(\\.)?)|" +
>
>       // 0[xX] HexDigits_opt . HexDigits BinaryExponent FloatTypeSuffix_opt
>       "(0[xX]" + HexDigits + "?(\\.)" + HexDigits + ")" +
>
>       ")[pP][+-]?" + Digits + "))" +
>      "[fFdD]?))" +
>      "[\\x00-\\x20]*");// Optional trailing "whitespace"
> if (Pattern.matches(fpRegex, myString))
>     Double.valueOf(myString); // Will not throw NumberFormatException
> else {
>     // Perform suitable alternative action
> }
> ```

> *"... When I enter the input `1+` and then when I try to enter `x^2`, it automatically exit from the app. I tried multiple Try catch block in order to stop the app from abruptly existing but it didn't work Below I have the code for onClick method of Square button ..."*

In this situation, you can use the *[String#substring](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,int))* method, to isolate the number.

```java
String string = tvMain.getText().toString();
string = string.substring(0, string.length() - 1);
```

Alternately, if you are unsure how many appended operators there may be, you can use a *loop* to trim the value.
In this case, while the last character is not a digit.

```java
String string = tvMain.getText().toString();
while (!Character.isDigit(string.charAt(string.length() - 1)))
    string = string.substring(0, string.length() - 1);
```

Here is a re-factor.

```java
String string = tvMain.getText().toString();
boolean valid = false;
double d = 0;
if (string != null && !string.isBlank()) {
    while (!Character.isDigit(string.charAt(string.length() - 1)))
        string = string.substring(0, string.length() - 1);
    try {
        d = Double.parseDouble(string);
        valid = true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException exception) { }
}
if (!valid)
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter a valid number..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
else {
    double square = d * d;
    tvMain.setText(String.valueOf(square));
    tvsec.setText(d + "²");
}
```